# Splitting a data.table with the by-operator: functions that return numeric values and/or NAs fail

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with two columns: one `ID` column and one `value` column. I want to split up the table by the `ID` column and run a function `foo` on the `value` column. This works fine as long as `foo` does not return NAs. In that case, I get an error that tells me that the types of the groups are not consistent. My assumption is that - since `is.logical(NA)` equals `TRUE` and `is.numeric(NA)` equals `FALSE`, `data.table` internally assumes that I want to combine logical values with numeric ones and returns an error. However, I find this behavior peculiar. Any comments on that? Do I miss something obvious here or is that indeed intended behavior? If so, a short explanation would be great. (Notice that I do know a work-around: just let `foo2` return a complete improbable number and filter for that later. However, this seems bad coding).

Here is the example:

```
library(data.table)
foo1 <- function(x) {if (mean(x) < 5) {return(1)} else {return(2)}}
foo2 <- function(x) {if (mean(x) < 5) {return(1)} else {return(NA)}}
DT <- data.table(ID=rep(c("A", "B"), each=5), value=1:10)
DT[, foo1(value), by=ID] #Works perfectly
     ID V1
[1,]  A  1
[2,]  B  2
DT[, foo2(value), by=ID] #Throws error
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , foo2(value), by = ID) : 
columns of j don't evaluate to consistent types for each group: result for group 2 has column 1 type 'logical' but expecting type 'numeric'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fix this by specifying that your function should return an `NA_real_`, rather than an `NA` of the default type.

```
foo2 <- function(x) {if (mean(x) < 5) {return(1)} else {return(NA)}}
DT[, foo2(value), by=ID] #Throws error
# Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , foo2(value), by = ID) : 
# columns of j don't evaluate to consistent types for each group: 
# result for group 2 has column 1 type 'logical' but expecting type 'numeric'

foo3 <- function(x) {if (mean(x) < 5) {return(1)} else {return(NA_real_)}}
DT[, foo3(value), by=ID] #Works
#      ID V1
# [1,]  A  1
# [2,]  B NA
```

Incidentally the message that `foo2()` gives when it fails is nicely informative.  It essentially tells you that your NA is of the wrong type. To fix the problem, you just need to look for the `NA` constant of the right type (or class):

```
NAs <- list(NA, NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_character_, NA_complex_)
data.frame(contantName = sapply(NAs, deparse), 
           class       = sapply(NAs, class),
           type        = sapply(NAs, typeof))

#     contantName     class      type
# 1            NA   logical   logical
# 2   NA_integer_   integer   integer
# 3      NA_real_   numeric    double
# 4 NA_character_ character character
# 5   NA_complex_   complex   complex
```

Comment: The more I work with `R`, the more I realize how much stuff I just don't know. This `NA_real_' trick is definitely one of it. So thanks @Josh O'Brien, great answer.

Comment: Thanks. I added a bit more about `NA` constants to my answer since this has often been useful to me, and it's an aspect of `NA` values that is typically invisible to users. Which is just as it should be!

Comment: What if you don't know the class ahead of time? Has been a big problem for me in data.table when using the `by=` argument. You ever run into a problem like this?

Comment: @rbatt The solution in cases like that (if I correctly understand your question) will be to ensure that the result returned by the function applied to each `by` group is always of the same type. [Here is an example that might help you see what I mean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12125882/980833). Scroll down in particular to the part where I wrap up the call to `median(X)` (which sometimes produces an `"integer"` and sometimes a `"numeric"` class object) in a call to `as.double()`, ensuring that the results will consistently have class `"numeric"`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Gotcha, thanks. So would you recommend just using a `switch(class(x), double = as.numeric(...), character = as.character(...), ...` type approach? For some functions it's clear that it should be a particular type. I was using a function with `unique` at its core, so the output could be any class. I ended up doing a workaround so I didn't have to specify the type of NA returned (just allowed `unique()` to do that for me). But it still raised the question for me. I could create a new question with more detail.

Comment: @rbatt Yeah, I'd suggest creating a new question with a minimial reproducible example that exhibits the behavior you're talking about. If you do that (perhaps linking to this and/or the other related answer), I'm sure you'll get a good response.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I asked a related question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34091811/2343633)