# Aggregation and typing inconsistency in `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question related to [Why does median trip up data.table (integer versus double)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125364/why-does-median-trip-up-data-table-integer-versus-double/12125882?noredirect=1#comment86578462_12125882). Except in my case I am using a maximum. I am excluding missing values. In base R, the max of a length 0 vector is `-Inf` which, interestingly is a double and not an integer. I think there may be a bug in `data.table`'s recent optimization routines.

Take this data table:

`dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,3,3,3), num = 1:6, log = c(F,F,F,T,F,T))`

If we perform:

`dt[, .(mnum = max(num[log], na.rm=T)), by=id]`

We find the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(mnum = max(num[log], na.rm=T)), by=id1] :
 Column 1 of result for group 2 is type 'integer' but expecting type 'double'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
```

Am I correct in thinking this is a bug or is there a syntactic omission here?

The expected output would, of course be

```
mnum id
-Inf  1
   6  3
```

Comment: the function call is missing a `)` after `na.rm=T`. But this might be an issue worth [reporting on Github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues).

Comment: @csgroen Thanks for the suggestion. Added an issue [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2737).

Comment: @csgroen also fixed the `)` which was a transcription error. I'm working off a terminal server where copy& paste is disabled. Crooks!

Comment: No problem! I couldn't reproduce the error and that's how I found the typo.

Comment: No, it is not a bug. `-Inf` is a double and `6L` is a float. `DT[, j, by=]` expects `j` to be a list of columns with consistent storage mode / type across the by= groups. I sort of think NA makes more sense than -Inf, there, in which case `dt[log == TRUE, .(mnum = max(num)), by=id][.(unique(dt$id)), on=.(id)]` works. Otherwise, maybe overwrite `num` as a double, with `as.double` or similar.

Comment: @Frank I think they have tried to address this, but not thoroughly. In my example I can run: `dt[-1, .(meannum = mean(num)), by=id]` without an error. The output `meannum` is cast to double type.

Comment: `mean` always gives a double, while `max` preserves type/mode.. except in the special case when it's taking the max of an empty int vector as in your example.

Comment: Btw, I posted a related problem to the issue tracker (related to IDate), dunno if it's solvable / reasonable to expect a solution to it https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2256

Comment: @Frank Thanks for explaining. I've learned something about `data.table` now. As a statistician (not a programmer) I favor accuracy over speed. It seems to me, if `data.table` optimized the mean/median to account for the frequent occurrence of double-type output, max/min could easily be considered the same, given that Inf/-Inf are commonly encountered values. Another option is setting `max <- function(...) {
ext <- base::max(...);
if (!is.finite(ext)) return(NA);
return(ext)
}`

Comment: Yeah, it sometimes requires more conscious thought about column types than I'd normally want to deal with. Btw, re the issue you posted, GForce only works on the simplest expressions, so max(x), not max(x[cond]). You can see this with verbose output on `dt[, .(mnum = max(num[log], na.rm=T)), by=id, verbose=TRUE]`

Comment: I would second @AdamO 's perspective on this - have run into the same  error a number of times recently, when all I want to do is get the median, max and min for some values by group.  I think this is such a common need that `data.table` should be able to handle it, especially since wrapping the functions in `as.double()` doesn't seem to prevent the error.  At least have an option for min, median and max for the user to specify that they want it all converted to double and don't mind the overhead?

Comment: Is there any update or a related upstream issue. I find it annyoing that even if you explicitly define the column type to be double it trips up the whole operation, why does it not fall back to the less efficient one, to complete a perfectly reasonable calculation.

Comment: I found that if I specified the initial colum type to be double (even when it is a series of integers) that I can get around the odd `data.table` peculiarity. But I definitely agree that it doesn't make much sense to have this issue -- or at the very least to have a more informative error message