# Why is a date being reformated to numeric value when passed into data frame?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I've created a data.frame by populating it with NA values

```
date_base <- rep(NA, df_length)
x <- rep(NA, df_length)
y <- rep(NA, df_length)

df1 <- data.frame(date_base,x,y)
```

I then cycle through some data and populate each row individually (hence the need for pre-populating the data.frame. Yes I could use rbind, but I thought this would be easier this way).

The first column is to contain dates which are formatted as `'yyyy-mm-dd'`. These are obtained from another data.frame `'in_data'` which is pulled from a database. I ensure they are dates using the as.Date function.

```
in_data$date_base <- as.Date(as.character(in_data$date_base),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

For each row I simple set:

```
df1$date_base <- end_date
```

Where end_date is a value from `in_data$date_base`. I've checked the data type of `end_date` and it's `Date[1]`

However once populated I check `df1$date_base` and they are numeric representations of the date: `14487, 14517, 14548` instead of `2009-08-31, 2009-09-30, 2009-10-31`

If instead of creating the data.frame with NA's I prepopulate with dates like:

```
date_base <- rep(as.Date(as.character('1970-01-01'),"%Y-%m-%d"), length(unique_dates) * versions_len)
```

then the resulting dates in df1 maintain the `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format in df1.

Why does populating the data frame with `NULL` values have this effect? Is this a bad practice to pre-populate a data.frame? If it is, what is best practice?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be as simple as making the first column a date initially as follows:

```
date_base <- as.Date(rep(NA, df_length))
```

When you set it as NA it creates it by default as a `logical` type rather than a `Date`. Here is a link to a previous question which describes this in more detail: [NA in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399592/na-in-data-table)

Comment: `NA` is logical, not integer.