# Why, for an integer vector x, does as(x, "numeric") trigger loading of an additional S4 method for coerce?

Tags: r, r-s4

While my question is related to [this recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34093056/980833), I suspect its answer(s) will have to do with the detailed workings of R's S4 object system.

### What I would expect:

(**TLDR;**  -- All indications are that `as(4L, "numeric")` should dispatch to a function whose body uses `as.numeric(4L)` to convert it to a `"numeric"` vector.)

Whenever one uses `as(object, Class)` to convert an object to the desired `Class`, one is really triggering a behind-the-scenes call to `coerce()`. `coerce()`, in turn, has a bunch of methods that are dispatched to based on the signature of the function call -- here the class of its first and second arguments. To see a list of all available S4 `coerce()` methods, one can run `showMethods("coerce")`.

Doing so shows that there is only one method for converting to class `"numeric"`. It's the one with signature `from="ANY", to="numeric"`:

```
showMethods("coerce")
# Function: coerce (package methods)
# from="ANY", to="array"
#      ... snip ... 
# from="ANY", to="numeric"
#      ... snip ...
```

That method uses `as.numeric()` to perform its conversion:

```
getMethod("coerce", c("ANY", "numeric"))
# Method Definition:
# 
# function (from, to, strict = TRUE) 
# {
#     value <- as.numeric(from)
#     if (strict) 
#         attributes(value) <- NULL
#     value
# }
# <environment: namespace:methods>
# 
# Signatures:
#         from  to       
# target  "ANY" "numeric"
# defined "ANY" "numeric"
```

Given its signature, and the fact that it's the only `coerce()` method for conversion to class `"numeric"`, 
I would've expected that the function shown above is what would be dispatched to by a call to `as(4L, "numeric")`. 
That expectation is only reinforced by running the following two checks.

```
## (1) There isn't (apparently!) any specific method for "integer"-->"numeric"
##     conversion
getMethod("coerce", c("integer", "numeric"))
# Error in getMethod("coerce", c("integer", "numeric")) : 
#   no method found for function 'coerce' and signature integer, numeric

## (2) This says that the "ANY"-->"numeric" method will be used for "integer"-->"numeric"
##     conversion    
selectMethod("coerce",  signature=c("integer", "numeric"))
# Method Definition:
# 
# function (from, to, strict = TRUE) 
# {
#     value <- as.numeric(from)
#     if (strict) 
#         attributes(value) <- NULL
#     value
# }
# <environment: namespace:methods>
# 
# Signatures:
#         from      to       
# target  "integer" "numeric"
# defined "ANY"     "numeric"
```

### What actually happens:

(**TLDR;** In fact, calling `as(4L, "numeric")` loads and dispatches to a method that does nothing at all.)

Despite what all indications mentioned above, `as(4L, "numeric")` does *not* dispatch to the `coerce()` method for calls with signature `c("ANY", "numeric")`.

Here are a couple of ways to show that:

```
## (1) as.numeric() would do the job, but as(..., "numeric") does not
class(as(4L, "numeric"))
#[1] "integer"
class(as.numeric(4L))
# [1] "numeric"

## (2) Tracing shows that the "generic" method isn't called
trace("coerce", signature=c("ANY", "numeric"))

as(c(FALSE, TRUE), "numeric")        ## <-- It's called for "logical" vectors
# Tracing asMethod(object) on entry   
# [1] 0 1

as(c("1", "2"), "numeric")           ## <-- and for "character" vectors
# Tracing asMethod(object) on entry   
# [1] 1 2    

as(c(1L, 2L), "numeric")             ## <-- but not for "integer" vectors 
# [1] 1 2

untrace("coerce")
```

What method, then, *is* used? Well, apparently the act of calling `as(4L, "numeric")` 
adds a new S4 method to the list of methods for `coerce()`, and it's what is used.
(Compare the results of the following calls to what they produced before we had attempted our
first `"integer"` to `"character"` conversion.)

```
## At least one conversion needs to be attempted before the  
## "integer"-->"numeric" method appears.
as(4L, "numeric")  

## (1) Now the methods table shows a new "integer"-->"numeric" specific method   
showMethods("coerce")    
# Function: coerce (package methods)
# from="ANY", to="array"
#      ... snip ... 
# from="ANY", to="numeric"
#      ... snip ...
# from="integer", to="numeric"        ## <-- Here's the new method
#      ... snip ...

## (2) selectMethod now tells a different story
selectMethod("coerce",  signature=c("integer", "numeric"))
# Method Definition:
# 
# function (from, to = "numeric", strict = TRUE) 
# if (strict) {
#     class(from) <- "numeric"
#     from
# } else from
# <environment: namespace:methods>
# 
# Signatures:
#         from      to       
# target  "integer" "numeric"
# defined "integer" "numeric"
```

### My questions:

1. Why does `as(4L, "numeric")` not dispatch to the available `coerce()` method for `signature=c("ANY", "numeric")`?
2. How/why does it instead add a new method to the S4 methods table?
3. From where (in R's source code or elsewhere) does the definition of the `coerce()` method for `signature=c("integer", "numeric")` come?

Comment: Interestingly, doing `trace("coerce", signature=c("integer", "numeric"))` in a fresh R session will actually trace the method for `signature=c("ANY", "numeric")` and will cause **that** method to be dispatched to by any subsequent calls to `as(4L, "numeric")` (for example).

Comment: The way I'm understanding it now, which I've said so much already, is that `as` bypasses `as.numeric` for integers in order to be consistent with `is.numeric` (that checks the *class*, not datatype) and maintain the idea that `integer` is a subclass of `numeric`. the "numeric" in `as.numeric` refers to the storage mode, not the class, so it shouldn't be used when converting the class of an integer vector to numeric.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde -- I definitely hear you, and that sounds plausible, but I feel like that's an answer to a question about the *motivation* or *rationale* for this behavior. I'm basically agnostic about that myself, and am instead trying to ask about the *mechanics* of what's happening here. (Why, for instance, isn't the method for `signature=c("integer", "numeric")` not simply included in the original/vanilla methods table for `coerce()`? If it was, I wouldn't be asking this question.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I think this motivation is the answer to your first question: because the available `coerce` method uses `as.numeric` and this isn't appropriate for integers because of the nuances of the class hierarchy. A possible answer to the second part of your second question might be that because `coerce` has been deprecated, the developers didn't want to explicitly add another method to the source. But I don't find that very satisfying.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien another thought is that creating the new method on the fly allowed R to be backward compatible with old code that uses `coerce`, from a time when there wasn't a distinction between the class numeric and storage mode numeric. If the code uses `as`, then the writer is operating under the new paradigm and the new integer method respecting the fact that integer is now a subclass of numeric gets added to the S4 methods table.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Where should I look to learn about or see how that on-the-fly method-creation takes place?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien it looks like the magic is happening in `.asCoerceMethod`, no?

Comment: `.asCoerceMethod` creates the function and `cacheMethod` adds it to the S4 methods table.

Comment: I'm still confused, though. After re-reading the documentation for `as.numeric`, I realize my conceptual model is backwards according to the "Note on names" section. This note says `is.numeric` checks the mode and `as.numeric` changes the class. I thought it ought to be the other way around, given the behavior of these functions and the fact that `is.numeric(1L)` is `TRUE` but `storage.mode(1L)` is `integer`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde `is.numeric()` tests the **mode**, not the **storage.mode**. (Confusing enough for you yet?) And yeah, based on what's `?as.numeric`, I do think your conceptual model was backwards. (Thanks for tracking down the site of that magic in the body of `as`.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I can answer your question exhaustively, but I'll try.

The help of the `as()` function states:

> The function ‘as’ turns ‘object’ into an object of class ‘Class’. In doing so, it applies a “coerce method”, using S4 classes and methods, but in a somewhat special way.
>
> [...]
>
> Assuming the ‘object’ is not already of the desired class, ‘as’ first looks for a method in the table of methods for the function 'coerce’ for the signature ‘c(from = class(object), to = Class)’, in the same way method selection would do its initial lookup.
>
> [...]
>
> If no method is found, ‘as’ looks for one. First, if either ‘Class’ or ‘class(object)’ is a superclass of the other, the class definition will contain the information needed to construct a coerce method. In the usual case that the subclass contains the superclass (i.e., has all its slots), the method is constructed either by extracting or replacing the inherited slots.

This is exactly what you can see if you look at the code of the `as()` function (to see it, type `as` (without the parentheses!) to the R console) - see below. First it looks for an `asMethod`, if it can't find any it tries to construct one, and finally at the end it executes it:

```
if (strict) 
    asMethod(object)
else asMethod(object, strict = FALSE)
```

When you copy-paste the code of the `as()` function and define your own function - let's call it `myas()` - your can insert a `print(asMethod)` above the `if (strict)` just mentioned to get the function used for coercing. In this case the output is:

```
> myas(4L, 'numeric')
function (from, to = "numeric", strict = TRUE) 
if (strict) {
    class(from) <- "numeric"
    from
} else from
<environment: namespace:methods>
attr(,"target")
An object of class “signature”
     from        to 
"integer" "numeric" 
attr(,"defined")
An object of class “signature”
     from        to 
"integer" "numeric" 
attr(,"generic")
[1] "coerce"
attr(,"generic")attr(,"package")
[1] "methods"
attr(,"class")
[1] "MethodDefinition"
attr(,"class")attr(,"package")
[1] "methods"
attr(,"source")
[1] "function (from, to = \"numeric\", strict = TRUE) "
[2] "if (strict) {"                                    
[3] "    class(from) <- \"numeric\""                   
[4] "    from"                                         
[5] "} else from"                                      
[1] 4
```

So, as you can see (look at `attr(,"source")`), the `as(4L, 'numeric')` simply assigns class `numeric` to the input object and returns it. Thus, the following two snippets are equivalent (for this case!):

```
> # Snippet 1
> x = 4L
> x = as(x, 'numeric')

> # Snippet 2
> x = 4L
> class(x) <- 'numeric'
```

Interestingly, both to 'nothing'. More interestingly, the other way round it works:

```
> x = 4
> class(x)
[1] "numeric"
> class(x) <- 'integer'
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
```

I'm not exactly sure about this (as the `class` method seems to be implemented in `C`) - but my guess would be that when assigning class `numeric`, it first checks whether it is already `numeric`. Which could be the case as `integer` is `numeric` (although not `double`) - see also the "historical anomaly" quote below:

```
> x = 4L
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
> is.numeric(x)
[1] TRUE
```

Regarding `as.numeric`:
This is a generic method and calls `as.double()`, which is why it 'works' (from the R help on `as.numeric`):

> It is a historical anomaly that R has two names for its floating-point vectors, ‘double’ and ‘numeric’ (and formerly had ‘real’).
>
> ‘double’ is the name of the type.  ‘numeric’ is the name of the mode and also of the implicit class.

Regarding questions (1) - (3): The magic happens in those four lines at the top of the `as` function:

```
where <- .classEnv(thisClass, mustFind = FALSE)
coerceFun <- getGeneric("coerce", where = where)
coerceMethods <- .getMethodsTable(coerceFun, environment(coerceFun), inherited = TRUE)
asMethod <- .quickCoerceSelect(thisClass, Class, coerceFun, coerceMethods, where)
```

Im lacking the time to dig into there, sorry.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for `as()`, it has two parts. (The source code has been shortened for clarity). First, it looks for existing methods for `coerce()`, as you described above.

```
function (object, Class, strict = TRUE, ext = possibleExtends(thisClass, 
    Class)) 
{
    thisClass <- .class1(object)
    where <- .classEnv(thisClass, mustFind = FALSE)
    coerceFun <- getGeneric("coerce", where = where)
    coerceMethods <- .getMethodsTable(coerceFun, environment(coerceFun), 
        inherited = TRUE)
    asMethod <- .quickCoerceSelect(thisClass, Class, coerceFun, 
        coerceMethods, where)

    # No matching signatures from the coerce table!!!
    if (is.null(asMethod)) {
        sig <- c(from = thisClass, to = Class)
        asMethod <- selectMethod("coerce", sig, optional = TRUE, 
            useInherited = FALSE, fdef = coerceFun, mlist = getMethodsForDispatch(coerceFun))
```

If it doesn't find any methods, as in this case, then it attempts to create a new method as follows:

```
        if (is.null(asMethod)) {
            canCache <- TRUE
            inherited <- FALSE

            # The integer vector is numeric!!!
            if (is(object, Class)) {
                ClassDef <- getClassDef(Class, where)
                if (identical(ext, FALSE)) {}
                else if (identical(ext, TRUE)) {}
                else {
                  test <- ext@test

                  # Create S4 coercion method here
                  asMethod <- .makeAsMethod(ext@coerce, ext@simple, 
                    Class, ClassDef, where)
                  canCache <- (!is(test, "function")) || identical(body(test), 
                    TRUE)
                }
            }
            if (is.null(asMethod)) {}
            else if (canCache) 
                asMethod <- .asCoerceMethod(asMethod, thisClass, 
                  ClassDef, FALSE, where)
            if (is.null(asMethod)) {}
            else if (canCache) {
                cacheMethod("coerce", sig, asMethod, fdef = coerceFun, 
                  inherited = inherited)
            }
        }
    }

    # Use newly created method on object here
    if (strict) 
        asMethod(object)
    else asMethod(object, strict = FALSE)
```

By the way, if you're only dealing with the basic atomic types, I would stick to base functions and avoid the `methods` package; the only reason to use `methods` is dealing with S4 objects.