# R: How come that "is" is TRUE, but "as" is impossible?

Tags: r

The [class "ecdf"](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ecdf.html) inherits from the class "stepfun". If `f` is such an empirical cumulative density function,
both `is.stepfun(f)` and `is(f,"stepfun")` are `TRUE`, and `as.stepfun(f)` doesn't do anything as expected.
But conversion of `f` to "stepfun" by `as(f,"stepfun")` is impossible because of the "metadata", even if `strict` is `FALSE`:

```
f <- ecdf(1:10)

class(f)
# [1] "ecdf"     "stepfun"  "function"

is.stepfun(f)
# [1] TRUE

is(f,"stepfun")
# [1] TRUE

identical(f,as.stepfun(f))
# [1] TRUE

g <- as(f,"stepfun",strict=FALSE)
# Error in as(f, "stepfun", strict = FALSE) : 
#   internal problem in as(): “ecdf” is(object, "stepfun") is TRUE, but the metadata asserts that the 'is' relation is FALSE
```

So how is `is` related to `as` and what is the meaning of the "metadata" here?

Comment: did you mean  `is.stepfun(f)` right after `class(f)` ?

Comment: I'm interested - where did you dig up the format `is(item,typedef)` as opposed to the format in all the help pages `is.typedef(item)` ?   You also might want to try  `methods(as)`  and a couple similar investigations to see what's going on with the `stepfun` class in particular.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: Searching for "R coercing" leads to the [documentation for the `as` method](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/as.html). Therein is a link ([setIs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/is.html)) to the [documentation for the `is` method](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/is.html).

Answer (score 2):

I may have found some relevant information.
 At [this nabble archive](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Apply-as-factor-or-as-numeric-etc-to-multiple-columns-td893777.html)

> ```
> but it has two problems: 
>
> 1) as() is an S4 method that does not always work 
> (problem 2 not relevant)
> ```

Locally  :-)   [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188128/error-in-asx-classk-no-method-or-default-for-coercing-null-to-data-fra/34188301#34188301)  has warnings about trying to use `as()`

So my suggestion would be to stick with  `as.stepfun(foo)`  .